# does array.shift() delete the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shift

i have an array that has one element and i want to use `proarray.shift();`

```
var proarray=[];
proarray[0]=1;
//...
proarray.shift();
//...
proarray[i]=5;
```

but when i do, it stops the program.
does it delete the array?
if it does, what should i do to prevent that? cuz i need that array for later.

and also i tried to use

```
var proarray=[];
    proarray[0]=1;
    //...
    array.splice(0,1);
    //...
    proarray[i]=5;
```

but it didn't work.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

> The shift method removes the element at the zeroeth index and shifts
>   the values at consecutive indexes down, then returns the removed
>   value. If the length property is 0, undefined is returned.

The program is likely stopping because you are accessing an index in the array that no longer exists.

Comment: @ali sorkhi Acceptable as the answer?